# ReentrantLock.lock() doesn't block other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, reentrantlock

I'm having a hard time understanding the behavior of ReentrantLock.lock()

I have the following class

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

class BlockingClass {

    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    private Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

    public void a() {
        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("called in method a(): lock()");

        try {
            System.out.println("called in method a(): await()");
            condition.await();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
            System.out.println("called in method a(): unlock() ");
        }
    }

    public void b() {
        lock.lock();
        System.out.println("called in method b(): lock()");

        System.out.println("called in method b(): signalAll()");
        condition.signalAll();

        lock.unlock();
        System.out.println("called in method b(): unlock() ");
    }
}
```

which I run with the following test:

```
class BlockingClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final BlockingClass blockingClass = new BlockingClass();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Thread1 calling a()");
                blockingClass.a();
            }
        }.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000); 

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Thread2 calling b()");
                blockingClass.b();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

I would have expected a deadlock. Once the a() method calls lock.lock(), I would expect that anyone calling the b() method would have to wait at b's lock.lock() until the thread calling a() had called lock.unlock(). But since a() is waiting for b() to call condition.signalAll(), both methods should have stayed blocked forever.

Instead, this is the output I get in the console:

```
Thread1 calling a()
called in method a(): lock()
called in method a(): await()
Thread2 calling b()
called in method b(): lock()
called in method b(): signalAll()
called in method a(): unlock() 
called in method b(): unlock()
```

What am I misunderstanding about the proper use and functioning of lock() and unlock()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not misunderstanding `ReentrantLock`, you're misunderstanding `Condition`. A `Condition` is bound to a lock and `Condition.await()` will effectively unlock, check and wait, and then relock the lock. See [`Condition.await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await%28%29).

In `a()`, between `lock()` and the call to `await()`, and between the return of `await()` and `unlock()`, your lock is behaving as you expect. Inside the call to `await()`, the `Condition` is managing it.

This is part of the general concept of a "condition variable"; it's why any thread library you find associates a lock of some sort with a condition (e.g. in POSIX C, [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) requires both a condition variable *and* a mutex).

Check out the Wikipedia article on [condition variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29#Condition_variables), it explains this behavior and the reasons for it in detail.

Comment: Thanks, @ortang and Jason C for your great and fast answers. I'm accepting this one simply for it's completeness and helpful documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `condition.await();` will release the lock, leaving the thread in a `wait` state, so thread b can just acquire the lock.

Your `a()` method will continue to run once `b()` has released it's lock, since you signaled the condition.

Comment: How do you explain the fact that `a() unlock()` happens before `b() unlock()`?

Comment: That's a race condition in your code. The `System.out.println("...");` method is called concurrently, since no lock is acquired anymore.

Comment: ^ You could put a printout just before the `unlock()` calls to see a somewhat more accurate view of the order of operations, @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been given but I thought I'd just quote the [javadocs for `Condition.await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await%28%29) to provide more context:

> Causes the current thread to wait until it is signalled or interrupted.
>
> The lock associated with this Condition is **atomically released** and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:
>
> 1. Some other thread invokes the signal method for this Condition and the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened; or
> 2. Some other thread invokes the signalAll method for this Condition; or
> 3. Some other thread interrupts the current thread, and interruption of thread suspension is supported; or
> 4. A "spurious wakeup" occurs.
>
> In all cases, before this method can return the current thread must re-acquire the lock associated with this condition. When the thread returns it is guaranteed to hold this lock.

So when you call `condition.await()` it releases the lock allowing the other thread to enter the locked section.  This is the same behavior as `Object.wait()` when inside of a `synchronized` code block.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to `Object.wait()`. That's very helpful as well.