# Second thread executed even though first thread locked using ReentrantLock

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization, reentrantlock

I am newbie in Java , trying to learn Java concepts with Implementation.
The reason for ReentrantLock class here is to understand Locks.

I am spawning 3 threads , and in these I just increment a Global Counter.
I am protecting the Counter overwrites by other thread using Locks.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class ReentryHandledSingleThread extends Thread
{
    static long counter = 0;

    private int myId;

    private final ReentrantLock myLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public ReentryHandledSingleThread(int id)
    {
        this.myId = id;
    }

    public void incrementTheCounter()
    {

        long stackvariable;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            stackvariable = ReentryHandledSingleThread.counter;
            stackvariable = stackvariable + 1;
            ReentryHandledSingleThread.counter = stackvariable;
        }
        System.out.println("The value from counter is " + ReentryHandledSingleThread.counter);
        return;

    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Started Thread No. " + this.myId);
        this.myLock.lock();
        {
            System.out.println("LOCKED Thread No. " + this.myId);
            this.incrementTheCounter();
        }
        System.out.println("UNLOCKED   Thread No." + this.myId);
        this.myLock.unlock();

    }
}

public class RentryHandle
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Started Executing Main Thread");
        int noOfThreads = 3;
        ReentryHandledSingleThread threads[] = new ReentryHandledSingleThread[noOfThreads];
        for (int j = 0; j < noOfThreads; j++)
        {
            threads[j] = new ReentryHandledSingleThread(j);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < noOfThreads; j++)
        {
            threads[j].start();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < noOfThreads; j++)
        {
            try

            {
                threads[j].join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Finished Executing Main thrread");

    }
}
```

***Observed Output from above code***

```
    Started Executing Main Thread 
    Started Thread No. 0 
    LOCKED Thread No.   0 
    Started Thread No. 2 
    LOCKED Thread No. 2 
    The value from counter is   10226 
    UNLOCKED   Thread No.0 
    The value from counter is 16165 
    UNLOCKED   Thread No.2 
    Started Thread No. 1 
    LOCKED Thread No. 1 
    The value from   counter is 26165 
    UNLOCKED   Thread No.1 
    Finished Executing Main   thrread
```

***My Expected Output***

```
    Started Executing Main Thread
    Started Thread No. 0
    LOCKED Thread No. 0
    The value from counter is 10000
    UNLOCKED   Thread No.0
    Started Thread No. 1
    LOCKED Thread No. 1
    The value from counter is 20000
    UNLOCKED   Thread No.1
    Started Thread No. 2
    LOCKED Thread No. 2
    The value from counter is 30000
    UNLOCKED   Thread No.2
    Finished Executing Main thrread
```

I went through [reentrantlock-lock-doesnt-block-other-threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133214/reentrantlock-lock-doesnt-block-other-threads)
However ,I am NOTusing here

> Condition.await()

Thus I was not able to co-relate with my implementation.
Please help me to understand the mistake or Understand ReentrantLock application in my implementation which is causing the diference in Exepected Output and observered output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that every thread object has its own lock (and is able to lock it independently of what all the other threads are doing):

```
private final ReentrantLock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

If you want the lock shared across the threads, make the above object `static`.

Comment: Thank you Sir..After making the
        private final ReentrantLock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
as
        private static final ReentrantLock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
I was able to get expected output.